# Expected value of the sum of the two largest values from a Uniform parent

Tags: probability, random-variables, uniform-distribution

Is the expected value of the sum of two greatest values in an uniform distribution in [0,1] of n random variables (x1,x2,x3,x4,...,xn) equal to E(max(x^n))+E(max(x^(n-1)))?

Comment: No. Not true even for $n=1$.

Comment: How must i procede?

Comment: Take a look at $n=1,2,3$

Comment: two maximum values are 2 and 3; (n), and (n-1)!

Comment: That comment makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability that $n-1$ of them are less than $x$ is $nx^{n-1}(1-x)+x^n$, so the PDF of the second-highest is the derivative of that.
If the second-highest is $x$, then the expected value of the sum of the top one is $(1+x)/2$, and the sum of the top two is $(1+3x)/2$.
Integrate the PDF of the second-highest, multiplied by $(1+3x)/2$.

Comment: Can you explain why the CDF is that

Comment: Sorry, I am a new user!

Comment: So $∫($($nx^{n-1}(1-x)$)$d$/$dx$*$(1+3x)/2$$)dx$

Comment: Solved! Thanks!

Comment: It looks like the expected value of the $k$th out of $n$ numbers is $k/(n+1)$.  Can you prove that?

Answer (score 0):

Let $X \sim \text{Uniform}(0,1)$ with pdf $f(x)$:

[image]

Let $X_n$ and $X_{n-1}$  denote the largest and second largest order statistics in a sample of size $n$. Then, the joint pdf of $(X_{n-1},X_n)$, say $g(x_{n-1},x_n)$, is:

[image]

where I am using the `OrderStat` function from the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica* to automate, or do it manually following:  [Wiki -- Joint Order Stats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#The_joint_distribution_of_the_order_statistics_of_the_uniform_distribution)

We desire $E_g[X_{n-1} + X_n]$ which is:

[image]

All done. As disclosure, I should perhaps add that I am one of the authors of the software used above.

Comment: Good, but I need steps to calculate it!

Comment: Solved! +1 for the contribute! Thanks!